# Galactic Ambitions Research, Stellaris Starchart Trade, Survey, Anomaly

Tags: stellaris

Is Anomaly only generated while surveying planets? If so, trading starchart (and Galactic Ambitions research) would be detrimental to solve some quest, let's say, like Cybrex one..

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Hadn't thought of that. That's a good question.

Comment: i would expect that if you share star charts, any unresolved anomaly sites would also appear on the details of the system,  however I can't prove that (no one wants to share star charts with me)

Comment: I can't say for sure, but from playing multiplayer, I know I've found anomalies in systems that another human player didn't.  I think that trading star information does prevent finding anomalies in systems, since you don't get to survey them.  I'll see about setting up this situation next time I play multiplayer.

Comment: well, it was my first playthrough as human (against AI).. and i got stuck solving things as another xenophile empires often offers me their starchart and i just blindly accepting the deal..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anomalies are unique to every player, i.e you can find an anomaly in a system another empire already surveyed.

However trading star charts automatically surveys the system for you permanently, this means, you can no longer survey it and any possible anomalies in there can no longer be discovered.

Galactic ambitions works different, it surveys systems temporarily as long as they are controlled by another empire. If you conquer the territory the system is no longer surveyed and can be scanned by your science ships.

So, in conclusion, if you want to avoid missing anomalies, never trade star charts, galactic ambitions is ok, unless you want to play pacifist, then you probably should not take it and survey systems in other empires by acquiring civilian access instead of conquering them.

source: personal experience

Comment: whoa, thank you for your explanation, looks like trading starchart or galactic ambitions is a no for solving quests.. those things pretty useful but it'll kill the benefit of anomalies.. looks like i had to restart my entire game..